# Log4j2 logging level becomes different in Java 8 and Java 11

Tags: log4j2

Log4j2 release 2.11.0 / 2.11.1 worked fine in Java 8 applications but not in Java 11

Here is an example of log4j2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">C:\\MyTestXXXX\\EnterpriseLogs</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="MyTestOnly" fileName="${log-path}\ServerLog.log" filePattern="${log-path}\ServerLog_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}_%i.log" append="true">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>[#%d{HH:mm:ss}|%p|%m#]%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 0 0 * * ?" evaluateOnStartup="true"/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy/>
        </RollingFile>  
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="OnlyLOG" additivity="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="MyTestOnly" level="ALL" />
        <Logger>

        <Root level="ALL" />
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

In the Java source code, I did this:
import org.apache.logging.log4j.*;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger;

```
...

// Get org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger
Logger logger = (Logger) LogManager.getLogger("OnlyLOG");
logger.log(Level.forName("INFO", 600), "Log this text now!", new Exception("xxxxxx"));
```

Running in Java 8, I can see that serverLog.log has the content, which is good.
Running in Java 11, there is no log.

Through further study (debugging), I found this line interesting:

```
Logger logger = (Logger) LogManager.getLogger("OnlyLOG");
```

After execution, in Java 8, logger was something like "ALL in 2f333739", and log was fine.
But in Java 11, logger was something like "ERROR in 2f333739" and there was no log. Obviously the level became "ERROR" instead of "ALL".

So, I tries this in Java 11:

```
Level loggerLevel = logger.getLevel(); // Obviously it is ERROR level
logger.log(loggerLevel, "Log this text now!", new Exception("xxxxxx"));
```

The log happened in console (likely went through Root), not in the ServerLog.log that was configured in log4j2.xml for logger OnlyLOG.

So, what caused the level difference between Java 8 and Java 11? In other words, what should be modified so that in Java 11, log can still work the same way as in Java 8?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved. Here is the reason.
I used a new Eclipse IDE to run Java 11, when adding a project, I added lib folder to the class path, since log4j2.xml was in the lib folder. Now I inspected the IDE configuration a second time and found out that the lib folder was not in the class path. After a second attempt, the configuration is fine and logging becomes normal.

I made a second test by adding a brand new project into the Eclipse IDE. Interestingly enough, when adding lib folder to the class path, indeed I had to try twice, because the first time it was not added. By the way, the computer runs Windows 10. This did not happen when using a computer running in Windows 7.

Regardless, Log4j2 works fine in both Java 8 and Java 11.